# Estimating the distribution of attributes over a city

Tags: distributions, estimation, sampling, gis

I have various shapefiles of attributes of a particular city, like the location of crimes, traffic accidents and greenspace.

I'd like to plot the distribution of these attributes over the whole city, the end goal is for a user to be able to enter a location and a search radius and be shown how the values of these attributes, like the crime density or percentage of area which is greenspace, occurring within that search radius compares to the distribution of those attributes over the whole city.

My first idea has been to take random samples of circular areas of the city, evaluate these attributes for each one and then divide by the area of the random sample to produce an estimate of the population distribution of these attributes per meter squared. Then when a user carries out a search, find the area of their search radius and multiply the estimated distributions by this area.

I'm also thinking of constraining the random samples to only consider areas where there are houses, large parts of the city are farmland or rural areas with virtually 100% of the area being greenspace and with no recorded crimes, the point of this tool is for a user to be able to compare different livable parts of the city with other parts so I'm concerned that including these areas would make livable areas appear worse than what they are because they are being compared alongside better but unlivable areas.

I'm struggling to find any resources on this. I'd like to be as rigorous as I can but I am not sure if this is a valid approach. I would be really grateful if someone could give me some advice or point me to some relevant resources as I have so many questions. Is there a way of calculating the number of samples that should be taken to produce an accurate estimate of the distribution? What effect does the radius of the sample have on the distributions and how would you go about deciding it? I'm thinking that up until a certain point, the smaller the search radius the better, but if they are too small then it might polarize the results. The locations of the crimes have been grouped and anonymized to be within 300m of their actual occurrence so would that mean a radius of 300m for the samples is appropriate as that's how precise the crime data is?

My plan at the moment is to take as many samples as my PC can handle in a reasonable amount of time, of 300m radius, constrained so that they contain livable spaces, but I can't really justify this method statistically, I'm very new to working with GIS data and I'm thinking I need to do some learning before going ahead with this, I would really appreciate it if someone could suggest where I do that.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: There's lots of literature on spatial analysis from [Openshaw's GAM](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DCluster/html/opgam.html) & GEM, through [Besag and Newell](https://rdrr.io/rforge/DCluster/man/besagnewell.html) and other more [statistical ones](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/multi-distance-spatial-cluster-analysis.htm) they all have pluses and minuses.